# How to fire direct event in row editing in gridpanel in ext.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ext.net

i'm using VB.net with ext.net (version 1.6).

i have a Gridpanel where i can double click on a row in order to edit it.
I can successfully edit it, but i need a direct event to be called whenever i finish editing ( in order to update the row in my database ).

I tried :

```
   <ext:Column ColumnID="Name" dataindex="Name"   Header="Field" Width="210" >
   <Editor>    
   <ext:TextField ID="TextField00" runat="server"  />                     
   </Editor>   
   </ext:Column>
```

and outside of the column :

```
      <DirectEvents>
      <AfterEdit OnEvent="UpdateFieldValue"></AfterEdit>
      </DirectEvents>
```

thanks

Comment: So, is UpdateFieldValue not called?

Comment: note that i am putting the directEvent outside the ColumnModel .. there is no afterEdit in the directEvent inside the column

Comment: Ok, I am posting a sample where it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in this example.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            Store store = this.GridPanel1.GetStore();
            store.DataSource = new object[] 
            { 
                new object[] { "test1" },
                new object[] { "test2" },
                new object[] { "test3" }
            };
            store.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridPanel_AfterEdit(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Alert("GridPanel_AfterEdit", "Hello from Server!").Show();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
        <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" AutoHeight="true">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server">
                    <Reader>
                        <ext:ArrayReader>
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:RecordField Name="test" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:ArrayReader>
                    </Reader>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <ColumnModel runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <ext:Column Header="Test" DataIndex="test">
                        <Editor>
                            <ext:TextField runat="server" />
                        </Editor>
                    </ext:Column>
                </Columns>
            </ColumnModel>
            <DirectEvents>
                <AfterEdit OnEvent="GridPanel_AfterEdit" />
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:GridPanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniil a lot .. i discovered a very silly error thanks to your post! me and my friend appreciate your initiative!!